# What other technology exists that are safer and simpler then cellular wavelength communication?

Tags: history

Communication without all the hassle. Is it to be presumed that cellular technology is the only form of external communication the world has to offer.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help], in particular [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to better understand the type of questions we appreciate here. For your question I have problem understanding if it is about world building at all. To me it sounds more like an electronic engineering question. Can you make this aspect more clear?

Comment: What do you mean by "cellular?"  Cellular technologies make up but a tiny fraction of the communications fabric we use today.

Comment: People interested in answering your question have to put in a lot of effort - **for free**! They have to come up with a new "safer and simpler" approach compared to what you say is the standard to the point where people think no alternatives exist and then they have to explain it in detail. The least you can do is show them that you appreciate it by writing more than 1 1/2 sentences and  no explanation or introduction to your world whatsoever. You will find that people here are extremely helpful if you put just a little bit more work into your question

Comment: I rolled back your edit because that picture adds nothing to the question and adding random pictures into posts is basically vandalism. Please take a look around the site to see how questions and answers are phrased.

Comment: This link here is the sandbox where you can post your "proposed" questions then people will contribute and tell you how you should create or make your questions a little bit clearer, I upvoted this question so that you can enter this site. https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6523/28224

Comment: I have no idea why you added that extra line into the comment, but I removed it because it added no value and made no sense.

Comment: @Shadowzee, FYI you can also use the rollback feature to revert edits

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it would be speaking, for that is the only thing I got from 10 minutes of brainstorming. If the message is an universal one, like shining a light at a plane means "help me", and that there is the appropriate materials, it could be done, but I wouldn't count on that as communication since you could not make it so that you send a complete sentence, but only what it has to offer, in this case, "help me".

Then, speaking is not that bad. You can instantaneously send a message at the speed of sound, one that most can comprehend if you're speaking in the same language, easily yes because people inside your speaking distance are often in the same country as you. You can also whisper, needing a closer distance but also safe from other peoples ears.

If this is in another world, not necessarily more high tech as this one, there could be underground lines which you connect to through an id, then put earphones on, not counting as wireless, then entering a number to connect to another person on the line. If there are enough lines, and people have specific glasses that allow only them to see their share of information on the line and alerting them, it could be good enough. There would just be people who don't understand why there are no cell phones with this technology.

Phones at home would be similar, since they are in the same place, it could allow for wired only connection, but it isn't as simple as cell phones.

In all of this case, the only method that allows the communication near to the simplicity and safeness of the cell phone is the ground lines.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of using other natural forces to tag on to to transmit ....such as light or water or even the effects of gravity on us that we can't necessary feel but is there.

Comment: Unless this spacial awareness observed phenomenon is unclear to you simply Imagen a bubble of water forced in a direction and that surface is reflecting a coded screen of information.

Comment: Obviously behind the scope of understanding around here.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that radio-frequency devices (including cell phones among countless others) *do* transmit using light. You could use a radio laser (raser?) instead of a broadcast, which has certain advantages and drawbacks, but the same principles would apply.